# Is Angular2 is always server side rendering?

Tags: angular

I encountered a problem with angular2 cli.
I use the cmd and type angular2 cli "ng build" the project, and I opened the index.html ,and I got "loading"  text and can't show the binding text. But I use "ng serve",then I get the page with the correct data.
And I try to find the whole html bundle file on the "/dist" folder,I can not find it.
Can anyone can help me,where the angular2 bundle the html file,I have no idea?browser or server side?

Answer (score 0):

Angular2 is rendered on the client side! There is a project called "Angular2 Universal" https://github.com/angular/universal which will support server-side rendering..

I assume there is a problem with some paths (relative/absolute) in your production build..
Just open your Dev-Tools of used browser and see what error message comes up..

Comment: I mixed up this framework,your answer is clear ,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you open `index.html` I understsand you open it directly per file url, like `C:\Documents\bla\index.html`? This will not work, you have to serve your application with an HTTP webserver and use an `http://` url.

This is exactly what `ng serve` does. It runs a webserver on port 4200 and then you can open your Angular 2 app thanks to that.

Comment: yes,this is the problem I got. your answer is clear .Thanks.